# Java - making a static reference to a non-static method

Tags: java, hibernate, static

For a project I am trying to create a class where I can pull data from a database using hibernate.

In this class I also try to make a list of objects made with the data pulled from the database through a DAO. But when I try to loop through the list eclipse alerts me that I am trying to make a static reference to a non static method.

I was under the impression that if you use an instance of an object(operator op in this case) that is not static and it doesn't refer to a static method that it could work.
Why doesn't this work and how do i fix it?

What especially confuses me is that the example code given by the teacher does the same thing but does work.

```
package Client.DAO;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

public class mainTest {

private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        entityManagerFactory = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

    operatorDAO dao = new operatorDAOImpl(em);
    List<operator> operators = dao.findAll();
    for (operator op : operators) {
        System.out.print("Id: " + operator.getID());// <-- This doesnt work
        System.out.print(", First Name: " + operator.getName()); // <-- This doesnt work

    }
}
}
```

For reference, working example code. Warning: Long

```
package nl.hu.ict;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

import nl.hu.ict.dao.HibernateUtil;
import nl.hu.ict.dao.LecturerDao;
import nl.hu.ict.dao.LecturerDaoHibImpl;
import nl.hu.ict.model.Lecturer;

public class MyHibernateTest {

private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // get the Hibernate - JPA entityManager
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        entityManagerFactory = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }

    // get the program (not necessary)
    // MyHibernateTest test = new MyHibernateTest();

    LecturerDao lectDao = new LecturerDaoHibImpl(em);
    Integer id;

    // handle the database actions

    // list all lecturers
    List<Lecturer> lecturers = lectDao.findAll();
    for (Lecturer lecturer : lecturers) {
        System.out.print("Id: " + lecturer.getID());
        System.out.print(", First Name: " + lecturer.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(", Last Name: " + lecturer.getLastName());
        System.out.println(", Last Name: " + lecturer.getLastName());
    }

    // add an lecturer
    Lecturer lect = new Lecturer();
    lect.setFirstName("Bill");
    lect.setLastName("Pianoman");
    lectDao.persist(lect);
    // get the id of the added lecturer
    id = lect.getID();
    // list to view changes
    lecturers = lectDao.findAll();
    for (Lecturer lecturer : lecturers) {
        System.out.print(lecturer);
    }

    // change a lecturer
    // find find it again
    lect = lectDao.findById(id);
    // change it
    lect.setFirstName("Billy");
    lectDao.update(lect);
    // list to view changes
    lecturers = lectDao.findAll();
    for (Lecturer lecturer : lecturers) {
        System.out.print(lecturer);
    }

    // delete a lecturer
    // find it again
    lect = lectDao.findById(id);
    // delete it
    lectDao.delete(lect);
    // list to view changes
    lecturers = lectDao.findAll();
    for (Lecturer lecturer : lecturers) {
        System.out.print(lecturer);
    }
    em.close();
    System.out.println("-- einde --");
}
}
```

Comment: Could you think out dramatically more easy example?

Comment: You're not using the object, you're using the class. operator.getID() should be op.getID()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is naming confusion; in this part of the code:

```
operatorDAO dao = new operatorDAOImpl(em);
List<operator> operators = dao.findAll();
for (operator op : operators) {
    System.out.print("Id: " + operator.getID());// <-- This doesnt work
    System.out.print(", First Name: " + operator.getName()); // <-- This doesnt work
}
```

You create a local variable named operators to refer to the list returned from the call to the DAO's findAll method. Within the for loop body you have a local variable op. The type of the local variable op is operator. But you're using "operator" as if it was the name of a variable. Change `operator.getID()` to `op.getID()`. The compiler thinks you're calling an instance method, getID, on the operator class, which is why you get the "static reference to a non-static method" error.

You can minimize these kinds of errors by following a naming convention. Types (classes and interfaces) should begin with an uppercase letter. Instance variables and local variables should begin with a lowercase letter. Following the convention this code becomes:

```
OperatorDAO dao = new OperatorDAOImpl(em);
List<Operator> operators = dao.findAll();
for (Operator operator : operators) {
    System.out.print("Id: " + operator.getID());
    System.out.print(", First Name: " + operator.getName());
}
```

Comment: Ah, you're right. im using operator instead of op, im an idiot. thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to use `op` instead of `operator` . The latter is a class name and you're trying to call method on that class which is not static.

Additionally,  java has very good convention which would help to quickly identify this problem - classes should start with uppercase while variables with lowercase

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print("Id: " + operator.getID());// <-- This doesnt work
System.out.print(", First Name: " + operator.getName()); // <-- This doesnt work
```

should be:

```
System.out.print("Id: " + op.getID());// <-- This doesnt work
System.out.print(", First Name: " + op.getName()); // <-- This doesnt work
```

You are trying to access the getID and getName as statics method when you want the instanced method.